# Flutter: Getting error in List when combining

Tags: list, flutter, class

Iam trying to shorten these steps

```
List<String> questionText = [
    'You can lead a cow down stairs but not up stairs.',
];
```

```
List<bool> questionAnswer = [
    false,
```

Combining these 2 List to single in another class but getting error in 'Question'

```
class Question {
  String questionText;
  bool questionAnswer;

  Question({required String q, required bool a}) {
    questionText = q;
    questionAnswer = a;
  }
}
```

//Error Here [Error Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xl4hq.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's written like this in dart.

```
class Question {
  String questionText;
  bool questionAnswer;

  Question({required this.questionText, required this.questionAnswer});
}
```

Check: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#constructors

Create an object like so:

```
Question question = Question(
   questionText: "You can lead a cow down stairs but not upstairs",
   questionAnswer: false,
);
```

Comment: How do i implement above change in this :-   `Question q1 = Question(q1: 'You can lead a cow down stairs but not up stairs.', a: false);`
I also tried this
  `Question q1 = Question(questionText: ('You can lead a cow down stairs but not up stairs.'), questionAnswer: false);` but it not worked

Comment: I've added an edit, @Yashkolte please check it.